# How do I overwrite my local repo with the one on github?

Tags: git, github

I've got an out-of-date repo with nothing to add on my machine. I want to pull in the latest stable branch from github.

Should I just clone over it? I'm not sure.

Comment: Just clone to a different directory, and trash the old one when you're sure you don't need anything from it.

Comment: Delete your local and re-clone.

Answer (score 8):

I think you should be able to do a fetch on all the files, then reset them to the origin:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

You could probably do it in either order, too.

If you want to remove any files you have added that aren't tracked, do a clean too:

```
git clean -f
```

The advantage to this approach over cloning to a new directory is that you will still retain some of the history/[reflog](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html).  If you absolutely do not care that data though, then either approach is fine.

Comment: Make sure to be on the `master` branch (i.e., `git checkout master`) before running the `git reset --hard` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just `git pull --all` should get the newest stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645171/how-do-i-overwrite-my-local-repo-with-the-one-on-github#comment22199423_15645171) and [meagar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645171/how-do-i-overwrite-my-local-repo-with-the-one-on-github#comment22199450_15645171) suggestions, but feel I should add a bit to them based on past experiences with using the `rm` command in Git projects.

If you are absolutely certain you don't want to keep anything from your directory containing the repo, `cd` to the level just above the folder so that you can remove it using `git rm`. I've found that using `git rm` is just neater than using a plain bash `rm`command. 
From a previous inscidident where I simply removed a file in my staging branch directory, I learnt that doing so threw the whole branch off track just because this wasn't logged in the *diff* record and if I tried a `git commit` it would output "Branch is up to date". A false positive.

Because you want to wipe the files as close to leaving no residual, hard-to-detect, or almost undetectable metadata chunks I'd say a *recursive forced removal* would be justified here. I.e, if the folder is called *MyRepo*, simply

> `git rm -rf MyRepo`

then just to double-check what I'd do is simply `cd MyRepo`, obviously expecting an error, because the folder shoudln't exist anymore.

Thereafter, proceed to clone your GitHub-hosted version in the same place as before, or anywhere you feel comfortable, and do what you normally do.

Comment: This is finally the answer I'm looking for. In order to test things from a completely clean environment, I want to remove anything local, then install it as if it were on a completely new machine. However, I don't want to run into such things as your not-logged-in-diff situation. This is the only answer that clearly describes how to do what I want to do.